# Ion RangeSlider custom function for slider val?

Tags: jquery, ion-range-slider

Can you use a function in the prefix like you can with prettify?  prettify is almost what i want, but it changes the grid values as well as the slider value.  I want to leave grid alone.

ex:  slider is $0 - $700.
If slider is on $220, i need to run some calculations and above slider dot display "1,250kWh / $220", without changing the grid values which are just dollar amounts user chooses.